# Smartsheet rows isnt updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, smartsheet-api, smartsheet-api-2.0

```
import smartsheet import pandas as pd     
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(token) 
response = smartsheet_client.Sheets.list_sheets(include_all=True) 
sheet1 = response.data 
sheet = smartsheet_client.Sheets.get_sheet(int(id))
sheet.rows[7].cells[1].value = "updated done right"
print(sheet.rows[7].cells[1].value)
```

the output is: "updated done right"
but when i refresh the smartsheet it doesn't update there why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write back to the service.  This only updates the local copy.  You can find an example of how to do this in the SDK Samples:

https://github.com/smartsheet-samples/python-read-write-sheet/blob/master/python-read-write-sheet.py

Comment: link to an answer is explicitly acceptable, but please put some context about how it solves the problem, e.g. in case broken link in the future. Please consider to check [answer]